# Refresh Lead Status (Path) in APEX

Tags: apex, visual-flows, salespath

I currently have a flow, which calls an apex class on completion.

This class changes my Status/Path of the lead.

I want to refresh the path (lighting component), when my flow finishes or when the apex class is ran.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done by using [platform events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro.htm).  Let's assume, you have a lighting component flow starting point. High level of steps are listed as above:

1. use `lightning:empApi` component to [subscribe to platform events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_lc.htm)
2. When the flow starts apex execution, publish event with some status = `Started` in this case show spinner for a user, that process is performing on background
3. On apex code, when it is finished. publish event with some status =`finished`
4. Handle event caught in lightning component by means of `lightning:empApi` and  refresh view as necessary.

topics that are useful: [How to use Platform Event in lightning by using lightning:empApi](http://simpluslabs.com/how-to-use-platform-event-in-lightning-by-using-lightningempapi/) [Emp API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation)